# Why I have to return the return of my function when calling OnSubmit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this JSP, look for the last line there is the main part of main question:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function validate() {
       if( $('#title_post').val() == "" || $('#content_post').val() == "" ){
            alert('Por favor preencha todos os campos da mensagem.');
            return false;
       }
       else
           return true;
   }
 </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#xdef").tagcloud({colormin:"d88",colormax:"0a0",height:300});    
    });
    function seta_type(obj){
        document.getElementById('topicType').value = obj;       
    }
</script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="col-left">
        <c:url value="/${company}/produto/${product}/topico/addtopic.html" var="linkPost"/>     
    <form:form action="${linkPost}" modelAttribute="topic" 
method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

That last line has a `return validate()` if I keep it that way, my form gives me an alert if the fields are not filled, ok that's what I want.

**My question is I tried to remove the return from that** and if I do that I get the alert but when I press ok, the servlet continues to its regular actions instead of staying in the same page...

Why is that?

BTW I am a new to JavaScript to explain it in detail please.

Comment: _"OnSubmit gives different result depending on the argument"_ - if you don't mind me pointing out the obvious, that's what arguments are for. If it gave the same results with different arguments that would be a problem...

Comment: putting the condescending part aside I changed it to something clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `return false` from your function `validate()`, that `false` value is not actually passed to the event handler. You need to `return` the result of the function straight to the `onsubmit` attribute. This could also be a good time to suggest attaching event handlers in your JavaScript code itself.

Think of it as kind of like this...

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    validate();
}, false);
```

Would that call to `validate()` pass its `false` to the event handler by magic? [Nope!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJP1DphOWPs)

Comment: But why doesnt calling the function do that if the function itself is returning a boolean?

Comment: Ah... Got it... but it looks really like a bad design... to have to return the return.

Comment: @contes: Check the example. It may make sense if you consider it that way.

Comment: @AdamRackis: A friend showed me. It made my day when I saw it :D

Comment: @alex - made my day too - +1 - now I have to send that to some people :)

Comment: _"but it looks really like a bad design... to have to return the return"_ - Another way to look at it is to consider what would happen if you did this: `onsubmit="func1(); validate(); funcX();"` - if `func1()` returned a value should it stop there and use that return, or use the return from `funcX()`, or...? You can also do something like `onsubmit="if(validate()){return true;}else {return someOtherFunc();}"` (I'm not saying you should code that way, but it is allowed, and highlights why you need to explicitly return a value...)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the form submission to cancel, you need to return false from the `onsubmit` handler.  By removing the return statement, you remove that behavior.

```
onsubmit="return validate();"
```

This actually **returns** the result of validate

Removing the return statement

```
onsubmit="validate();"
```

just **calls** validate, but doesn't return its result.

**The onsubmit handler must itself return false to cancel the form submission**

Comment: But why doesnt calling the function do that if the function itself is returning a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

when the validation is failing, you have to return false to the form element to cancel the form submission request. If you return true to form, it continues with form submission request.